# Switching from object mode to edit mode screws up my curtain

Tags: animation, edit-mode, object-mode

I'm trying to create a curtain by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVvOk_7PoUE) video.

After I create a grid, rotate it, pin the top vertices to the grid, create the hook from these vertices, add cloth to the grid and then finally start to animate the curtain by scaling the hook, if I go back to edit mode and then back to object mode the grid model gets screwed like showed in the image below. Sometimes I encountered this issue even when not switching from object mode and edit mode but this is the only consistent way I found to replicate it
[image]

I made a video showing exactly what I do to reproduce this behaviour. What am I doing wrong?
https://youtu.be/CfYM709SOXg

Comment: I guess it will work fine if you bake the simulation

Comment: thank you for you comment. Yes it does but I would like to know why that is happening